# tkinter GUI writing to a text widget and replacing text

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

parent = Tk()

p = ttk.Panedwindow(parent, orient=HORIZONTAL)
p.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

p1 = ttk.Panedwindow(parent, orient=HORIZONTAL)
p1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
f4 =ttk.Labelframe(p1, text='marks numbers histograms', width =400, height = 100)

p1.add(f4)

# declare and set variable(s)
marks_to_hist = StringVar()


# ROUTINE OPENS MARKS , TALLIES RANGES, DRAWS HISTOGRAM
def open_marks_numbers():

    N = int(marks_to_hist.get())
    N = N * 5
    marks = []
    for line in open('marks.txt').readlines():
       datafile = (line.strip().split('\t')[0].split(','))  
       for n in datafile:
          marks.append(int(n))
    marks=marks[:N]
    return marks

def open_numbers_for_draw(n):
    marks = open_marks_numbers()
    return marks[n-1::5]

def count_marks_range(numbers):
    marks_range_tally = [0] * 12
    for num in numbers[:]: 
        which_range=int(num//5)
        marks_range_tally[which_range] = marks_range_tally[which_range] + 1
    return marks_range_tally

def get_marks_tally():
    marks_range_tally = []
    draw_nums = [1,2,3,4,5] #or range(1,6)
    for n in draw_nums:
        numbers = open_numbers_for_draw(n)
        marks_range_tally.append(count_marks_range(numbers)) #create histogram, append to list
    return marks_range_tally

def write_histogram_marks():
    '''
    histogram format:
    1 - 4    **
    5 - 9    ***
    10 - 14  ******
    15 -19   **
    45 - 49  ****
    50       *

   '''
    import tkinter.filedialog
    histfilesaved =tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()
    histfile=open(histfilesaved,'w')
    marks_range_tally = get_marks_tally()
    # convert list to integers using list comprehension
    marks_count1 = [int(i) for i in marks_range_tally[0]]
    marks_count2 = [int(i) for i in marks_range_tally[1]]
    marks_count3 = [int(i) for i in marks_range_tally[2]]
    marks_count4 = [int(i) for i in marks_range_tally[3]]
    marks_count5 = [int(i) for i in marks_range_tally[4]]


    print(marks_count1 ,'\n', marks_count2, '\n' , marks_count3 , '\n', marks_count4 , '\n' , marks_count5)

    histfile.write('distribution of marks numbers \n')

    histfile.write('1-4:    ')
    histfile.write('*' * marks_count1[0])
    histfile.write(' ' * (22  -marks_count1[0]))
    histfile.write('1-4:    ')
    histfile.write('*' * marks_count2[0])
    histfile.write(' ' * (22  -marks_count2[0]))
    histfile.write('1-4:    ')
    histfile.write('*' * marks_count3[0])
    histfile.write(' ' * (22  -marks_count3[0]))
    histfile.write('1-4:    ')
    histfile.write('*' * marks_count4[0])
    histfile.write(' ' * (22  -marks_count4[0]))
    histfile.write('1-4:    ')
    histfile.write('*' * marks_count5[0])
    histfile.write('\n')

    histfile.write('5-9:    ')
    histfile.write('*' * marks_count1[1])
    histfile.write(' ' * (22 -marks_count1[1]))
    histfile.write('5-9:    ')
    histfile.write('*' * marks_count2[1])
    histfile.write(' ' * (22 -marks_count2[1]))
    histfile.write('5-9:    ')
    histfile.write('*' * marks_count3[1])
    histfile.write(' ' * (22 -marks_count3[1]))
    histfile.write('5-9:    ')
    histfile.write('*' * marks_count4[1])
    histfile.write(' ' * (22 -marks_count4[1]))
    histfile.write('5-9:    ')
    histfile.write('*' * marks_count5[1])
    histfile.write('\n')
    for i in range(2,10):
        low =  i * 5
        high = i * 5 + 4
        histfile.write(str(low) + '-' + str(high) + ':  ')
        histfile.write('*' * marks_count1[i])
        histfile.write(' ' * (22 -marks_count1[i]))
        histfile.write(str(low) + '-' + str(high) + ':  ')
        histfile.write('*' * marks_count2[i])
        histfile.write(' ' * (22 -marks_count2[i]))
        histfile.write(str(low) + '-' + str(high) + ':  ')
        histfile.write('*' * marks_count3[i])
        histfile.write(' ' * (22 -marks_count3[i]))
        histfile.write(str(low) + '-' + str(high) + ':  ')
        histfile.write('*' * marks_count4[i])
        histfile.write(' ' * (22 -marks_count4[i]))
        histfile.write(str(low) + '-' + str(high) + ':  ')
        histfile.write('*' * marks_count5[i])
        histfile.write('\n')
    histfile.write('50:     ')
    histfile.write('*' * marks_count1[-1])
    histfile.write(' ' * (22 -marks_count1[-1]))
    histfile.write('50:     ')
    histfile.write('*' * marks_count2[-1])
    histfile.write(' ' * (22 -marks_count2[-1]))
    histfile.write('50:     ')
    histfile.write('*' * marks_count3[-1])
    histfile.write(' ' * (22 -marks_count3[-1]))
    histfile.write('50:     ')
    histfile.write('*' * marks_count4[-1])
    histfile.write(' ' * (22 -marks_count4[-1]))
    histfile.write('50:     ')
    histfile.write('*' * marks_count5[-1])
    histfile.write('\n')
    histfile.close()
# ENDS marks NUMBERS FUNCTION

def evClear():
   num_draws.delete(0, END) ()# clears entry but causes error
   num_draws.focus() # places the cursor into the text box

def replace_histogram():

    data=open('histfile.txt','r')
    myData= data.read() # read the file to variable
    data.close()
    ViewHistogramWidget.insert(0.0,myData)
'''
BOTTOMFRAME (LEFT)
marks NUMBERS HISTOGRAMS
'''

from_lbl = Label(f4, text='how many records ? ', font='comic-sans-MS')
from_lbl.pack(side=TOP) 
num_draws =Entry(f4, textvariable=marks_to_hist, font='comic-sans-MS', width='2',insertbackground= 'red')
num_draws.pack(side=TOP) # enter number of records
enter_btn1 = Button(f4,text='draw new histogram', font='comic-sans-MS', command=replace_histogram)
enter_btn1.pack(side = BOTTOM, padx = 25)
clear_btn = Button(f4, text='clear', font='comic-sans-MS', command = evClear)
clear_btn.pack(side=BOTTOM, padx = 5)
ViewHistogramWidget= Text(f4,  width = 150) # set up a text widget as a root (window) child


with open('histfile.txt','r') as data:
   myText= data.read() # read the file to variable
   data.close() # close file handle

ViewHistogramWidget.insert(0.0,myText) # insert the file's text into the text widget

ViewHistogramWidget.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH) # show the widget
mainloop()
```

marks data is in a comma delimited file with five marks per record 
e.g

```
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,3
```

histfile is a simple textfile.

This 'routine' correctly displays the output of a histfile generated by `write_histogram_marks()`.

What I want it to be able to do is to generate a new histogram file based on a user-defined desired number of records (input into the variable `marks_to_hist`), and write the new file to the text window (erasing the previous display). However using the `replace_histogram` simply rewrites the same file below the one already displayed. Also the `evClear` button I would like to use to clear both the entry field and the text window. At the moment it erases the entry but generates an error. I am sure that my histfile.write procedure is utterly clumsy and repetitive, but this is the only way for a 'newbie' like me could figure it out.

Have to say that I have had a lot of help from folk on stackOverflow to get this far. Help much appreciated

Comment: In case I have not made it clear, I would appreciate help with the histogram writing problems, if someone is willing. My problems are the evClear to clear both the textWidget and the entry field and then getting the replace_histogram to call a rewrite of the histfile and display this erasing the first display at the same time. I would appreciate help, please

Answer (score 9):

Use following classes and replace Text and Entry widgets, utilizing new setText and clear methods:

```
import Tkinter

class HistogramViewer(Tkinter.Text):
    def setText(self, text):
        self.clear()
        self.insert(Tkinter.END, text)

    def clear(self):
        self.delete("1.0", Tkinter.END)


class HistogramEntry(Tkinter.Entry):
    def setText(self, text):
        self.clear()
        self.insert(0, text)

    def clear(self):
        self.delete(0, Tkinter.END)
```

Improved based on notices from Bryan Oakley.

Comment: The proper starting index is 0 -- entry widgets don't use the line.column format of text widgets. Also, you might want to show how to delete text in the text widget, since that was part of the question.

Comment: Also, Text widget line numbers start at 1. the proper starting index is "1.0" and should be a string rather than a floating point number.

Comment: Wait, so there's a built-in method to append text, but not to simply set the text?

Comment: @flarn2006: Yep.

Comment: @martineau: That seems awfully bizarre.