# I need help in Python with displaying the contents of a 2D Set into a Tkinter Textbox

Tags: python-3.x

**Disclaimer:** I have only begun to learn about Python. I took a crash course just to learn the very basics about a month ago and the rest of my efforts to learn have all been research thru Google and looking at solutions here in Stack Overflow.

I am trying to create an application that will read all PDF files stored in a folder and extract their filenames, page numbers, and the contents of the first page, and store this information into a 2D set. Once this is done, the application will create a tkinter GUI with 2 listboxes and 1 text box. 
The application should display the PDF filenames in the first listbox, and the corresponding page numbers of each file in the second listbox. Both listboxes are synched in scrolling.

The text box should display the text contents on the first page of the PDF.
What I want to happen is that each time I click a PDF filename in the first listbox with the mouse or with up or down arrow keys, the application should display the contents of the first page of the selected file in the text box.

This is how my GUI looks and how it should function

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrkvo.jpg

I have been successful in all other requirements so far except the part where when I select a filename in the first listbox, the contents of the first page of the PDF should be displayed in the text box.

Here is my code for populating the listboxes and text box. The contents of my 2D set pdfFiles is [['PDF1 filename', 'PDF1 total pages', 'PDF1 text content of first page'], ['PDF2 filename', 'PDF2 total pages', 'PDF2 text content of first page'], ... etc.

===========Setting the Listboxes and Textbox=========

```
scrollbar = Scrollbar(list_2)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
list_1.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
list_1.bind("<MouseWheel>", scrolllistbox2)
list_2.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
list_2.bind("<MouseWheel>", scrolllistbox1)
txt_3 = tk.Text(my_window, font='Arial 10', wrap=WORD)
txt_3.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.12, relwidth=0.472, relheight=0.86)
scrollbar = Scrollbar(txt_3)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
list_1.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", CurSelect)
```

============Populating the Listboxes with the content of the 2D Set===

```
i = 0
while i < count:
    list_1.insert(tk.END, pdfFiles[i][0])
    list_2.insert(tk.END, pdfFiles[i][1])
    i = i + 1
```

============Here is my code for CurSelect function========

```
def CurSelect(evt):
    values = [list_1.get(idx) for idx in list_1.curselection()]
    print(", ".join(values)) ????
```

========================

The print command above is just my test command to show that I have successfully extracted the selected item in the listbox. What I need now is to somehow link that information to its corresponding page content in my 2D list and display it in the text box.

```
Something like:
1) select the filename in the listbox
2) link the selected filename to the filenames stored in the pdfFilename 2D set
3) once filename is found, identify the corresponding text of the first page
4) display the text of the first page of the selected file in the text box
```

I hope I am making sense.  Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need much to finish it. You just need some small things:
1. Get the selected item of your `listbox`:

```
selected_indexes = list_1.curselection()
first_selected = selected_indexes[0]  # it's possible to select multiple items
```

2. Get the corresponding PDF text:

```
pdf_text = pdfFiles[first_selected][2]
```

3. Change the text of your `Text` widget: (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/20908371/8733066)

```
txt_3.delete("1.0", tk.END)
txt_3.insert(tk.END, pdf_text)
```

so replace your `CurSelect(evt)` method with this:

```
def CurSelect(evt):
    selected_indexes = list_1.curselection()
    first_selected = selected_indexes[0]
    pdf_text = pdfFiles[first_selected][2]
    txt_3.delete("1.0", tk.END)
    txt_3.insert(tk.END, pdf_text)
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you -- I did not know you could use the selected text as a means to search thru the set. I had been researching about how to do this for a whole week!